# Can i use .env file variables in CSS?

Tags: css, environment-variables, frontend, less, environment

i'm tryng to use a .env file variable in a less/css file, is that even possible?
I've already used some of these variables in php files with $_ENV['VARIABLE']. Thank you!

Comment: What is your end goal here? What are you trying to do by having access to the `.env` file in your CSS?

Comment: import a css file from web which is declared as a variable in .env

Answer (score 1):

No, `.env` is for environment variables, even if it possible to use from a `less` file it shouldn't be used.